# string manipulations for ajax send to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'v got troubles whit html special characters when I tried to send string via Ajax (jQuery) to php ? For exemple, on client side, in a content editable div, the client write : "*My brain & my head are not > than yours*", but the string I get with innerHTML stop at "&".
Actually i'm looking for the best way to built my own text-editor...

Don't hesitate to ask more details...

client side js script :

```
function uncode(id) { 
    var str = id.innerHTML;
    str = str.replace(/&apos;/gi, '\'')
            .replace(/&quot;/gi, '\"')
            .replace(/&amp;/gi, '\&')
            .replace(/&lt;/gi, '\<')
            .replace(/&gt;/gi, '\>')
            .replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ');
    return str; 
} 

$('#saveText').click(function () {

    var str = uncode(document.getElementById('myText'));
    var myDatas = 'update_bio=update_bio' + '&new_bio=' + str + '&id_bio=' + id_str[1];     

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: mypage.php,
        data: myDatas,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        encoding: 'UTF-8',
    });
});
```

Server side :

```
$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', 'root', 'root', $pdo_options);
            $bdd->query('SET NAMES utf8');

if (!empty($_POST['update_bio'])) {
    $reponse = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE bios SET texte=:new_bio WHERE id=:id_bio');
    $reponse->execute(array(
        'new_bio' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['new_bio']),
        'id_bio' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['id_bio'])
    ));
    $reponse->closeCursor();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery why don't you use `text()`?, it should work.
No encoded: http://jsfiddle.net/CDTQb/
Encoded: http://jsfiddle.net/CDTQb/2/

Comment: I used innerHTML to keep html tags (for the layout modification of the user). For my text editor, I used button controlled by the execCommand function. It creates HTML tags like `<span _moz_dirty="" style="font-weight: bold;">Text en gras</span>`. So I need to preserve tags but also to save the text from pirats script... Does the text() function help me to do that ?